# SonataAdmin Install issue

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata, symfony-3.2

I trying to install SonataAdmin on my Symfony Project but at the end of the part-2 of the documention when i'm trying to go on "http://localhost:8000/admin/" I have a error : *"You have requested a non-existent service "admin.category" in . (which is being imported from "C:\wamp64\www\Sonata/app/config\routing.yml"). Make sure there is a loader supporting the "sonata_admin" type."*

I have no idea why, i give give my all my parameters code maybe it's can help you to understand my problem.

parameters:
    #parameter_name: value

services:

```
# default configuration for services in *this* file
_defaults:
    # automatically injects dependencies in your services
    autowire: true
    # automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.
    autoconfigure: true
    # this means you cannot fetch services directly from the container via $container->get()
    # if you need to do this, you can override this setting on individual services
    public: false

admin.category:
    class: AppBundle\Admin\CategoryAdmin
    arguments: [~, AppBundle\Entity\Category, ~]
    tags:
        - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, label: Category }


# makes classes in src/AppBundle available to be used as services
# this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
AppBundle\:
    resource: '../../src/AppBundle/*'
    # you can exclude directories or files
    # but if a service is unused, it's removed anyway
    exclude: '../../src/AppBundle/{Entity,Repository,Tests}'

# controllers are imported separately to make sure they're public
# and have a tag that allows actions to type-hint services
AppBundle\Controller\:
    resource: '../../src/AppBundle/Controller'
    public: true
    tags: ['controller.service_arguments']

# add more services, or override services that need manual wiring
# AppBundle\Service\ExampleService:
#     arguments:
#         $someArgument: 'some_value'
```

`

The indentation is going wrong i add you a picture of this file. [Service code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncO7Q.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you did a mistake by writing your `category.admin` service in: Sonata/app/config/routing.yml, 
instead of **Sonata/src/YourAdminBundle/Resources/config/services.yml**

Comment: In my routing.yml there is only : `app:
    resource: '@AppBundle/Controller/'
    type: annotation

admin_area:
    resource: "@SonataAdminBundle/Resources/config/routing/sonata_admin.xml"
    prefix: /admin


_sonata_admin:
    resource: .
    type: sonata_admin
    prefix: /admin
`

Comment: Alright I misunderstood which file was matching your code block above, it's services.yml (in app/config) right ? so you should cut your `category.admin` block  and paste it in the file i mentioned, that's where you have to declare admin classes

Comment: Yes it's the app/config/service.yml file. But my project is actually empty. I only have sonata in it i just wanna test it on a empty projet before using it on a real project. I will try to do that on a real project we will see

Answer (score 0):

The sonata admin services must be public. In your config, you have default as `public: false` and that is why you get this error.

So you have 2 options:

1. Specify `public: true` for your admin service (in your example file)
2. Or the better way: create a new services file (eg admin.yml) where you dont use these defaults (the `_defaults` key with `public: false`). Public is `true` by default, so you don't have to specify that by `_defaults`. In this case you must import your new file in `config.yml` to work:

Top of `app/config.yml`

```yml
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: services.yml }
    - { resource: admin.yml }
```

`app/admin.yml` content:

```yml
services:
    admin.category:
        class: AppBundle\Admin\CategoryAdmin
        arguments: [~, AppBundle\Entity\Category, ~]
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, label: Category }
```

Answer (score 0):

Run this command on terminal. Because You might have missed installing

```
php composer.phar require sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle
```

After This Add this code below to your AppKernel.php

// app/AppKernel.php

```
public function registerBundles()
{
    return array(
        // ...
        // set up basic sonata requirements
        // ...
        new Sonata\DoctrineORMAdminBundle\SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle(),
        // ...
    );
}
```